# Are diamonds as chemically inert as glass?

Tags: crystal-structure, glass

Every beaker that I have seen in a lab is made of glass. Glass, as I understand, is made of SiO2, or silicon dioxide, which has a crystalline structure that is similar to diamond. This property causes both diamonds and glass to be chemically inert. My question is, (ignoring the costs and technicalities of production), could beakers be feasibly made out of diamonds? Following up on this question, are there solutions that can dissolve glass effectively? What about solutions that can dissolve diamonds?

Comment: No feasibility as there is no significant chemical advantage over the glass and the cost involved.

Comment: Don't omit that burning diamond is difficult but it can be done.

Answer (score 4):

Diamonds are chemically inert. They burn at very high temperatures, but apart from this, they don't react. They are insoluble in all sorts of solvents, with the exceptions of iron above its melting point (~1500°C}. Glass is not really chemically inert. It is slowly attacked by concentrated solution of NaOH, or by pure NaOH above its melting point. It is also attacked by hydrofluoric acid HF.

Comment: Does diamond really dissolve in iron, but as what? By dissolution, I mean one can recover them after dissolving iron in acid. Never

Comment: Iron with dissolved carbon is steel. Can you get carbon from steel by dissolving iron in an acid? I don't think so.

Comment: When diamond is dissolved into iron, it cannot be recovered later on after dissolving in an acid. The only substance to be recovered is amorphous carbon, or iron carbide.

Comment: Diamonds are *less* chemically inert that lab glassware. For example they will burn at temperatures which would merely *melt* lab glassware (which is done to manipulate it into different shapes.).

Comment: @matt_black It's not a competition. ;)

Comment: "functionalized diamond" gives five million hits on google. ;)

Comment: The comment above makes me to want point out that dissolving something it just means getting it dissolved. Finer details and mechanisms are not included in asserting that X dissolves Y.