Can a diamond dissolve in molten iron?
The melting point of diamond is 4000C and the melting point of iron is 1538C. However, the question is if a diamond is soluble in an iron solvent. Diamond is made up of carbons. And I know steel is made of carbon and iron. So, can diamond combine with iron? Would that occur by dropping a diamond into molten iron and it would dissolve?

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/182101/is-anything-other-than-metals-soluble-in-molten-metals-alloys

Yeah, it would dissolve, but how fast is an issue.

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/34193/are-diamonds-really-forever https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/145115/are-diamonds-as-chemically-inert-as-glass

You could even burn 'em: https://www.iflscience.com/the-scientist-who-burned-diamonds-to-prove-that-they-were-carbon-69434 . Lavoisier did, though his career was cut short.

Carbon not diamond. At low pressure and high temperature it turns into graphite before reacting with iron.
